# Unity3D Custom Collider

Tags: c#, unity3d

В Update cтреляем лучом по коллайдеру и получаем у него нужный нам родительский объект.

```
Physics.Raycast(weapon.position, weapon.forward, out gunsightHit, 200, HitMask);
Collider _col = gunsightHit.collider;
```

Получаем из него объект

```
victim = _col.GetComponentInParent<VictimScript>();
```

И что то с ним делаем.

Вопрос - вышеприведённые методы довольно таки просаживают FPS, так как GetComponent в Update.

Предполагаемое мной решение - сделать к Collider некий AttachedScript,аналогично AttachedRigidbody. Чтобы вместо GetComponent просто написать что то вроде

```
victim = _col.attachedScript;
```

Но не нашёл в сети ничего подобного. 
Как подобное можно реализовать? Чтобы у всех Collider появилось дополнительное поле в редакторе, куда можно поставить какой нибудь объект - для ссылки на него при попадании луча.

Если это крайне труднореализуемо(исходники Unity вроде как закрыты), то подскажите альтернативный способ решения проблемы производительности при применении подобной связки(Raycast->Collider->GetComponent)

Comment: что мешает как минимум при инициализации объекта хранить ссылку на своего `VictimScript`?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Уточню - victim не один. Их много, они появляются и исчезают. Но в принципе вполне вероятно. А вышеприведённый путь, что вы скажете о нем?

Comment: `Уточню - victim не один. Их много` -  и что? причем тут это? ты же стреляешь по конкретному.... вот когда ты делаешь `Instantiate` объекта, то в его `Start()` методе просто инициализируешь ссылку на тот компонент, в котором в итоге у тебя что-то происходит......................А вообще можно использовать события, без всяких GetComponent. Отсылать событие ударенному врагу, пусть у себя там отнимает жизни

Comment: подобный подход реализовать не получится. Во-первых закрыты исходники, во вторых теоретически в c# возможно сделать то, что вы хотите, но для этого класс, который вы хотите расширить должен быть помечен как partial, но в данной ситуации увы

Answer (score 0):

Практически точно ничего из этого хорошего не получится.

Можно попробывать написать что-то "лучше" чем `GetComponent`, но если получится - можно смело пушить это в Unity3d репозиторий.

Подобные проблемы я решал добавлением корутины. Обычно нет требований делать проверки в каждом кадре - можно сделать корутину с необходимым временем обновления (.1f секунды обычно достаточно).

```
IEnumerator Do()
{
  while (true)
  {
    Physics.Raycast(weapon.position, weapon.forward, out gunsightHit, 200, HitMask);
    var _col = gunsightHit.collider;
    victim = _col.GetComponentInParent<VictimScript>();

    //PROFIT

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(.1f);
  }
}
```